# bootstrap dropdown menu,official example,page is blank

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>
  test
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
  
   </body>
```

I just follow the official web site writing a dropdown menu, but I can see nothing in the browser, and no errors in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the dropdown containing div and a button to open the dropdown menu.  Here's a working example:

```html
<html>  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        test
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

   </body>
</html>
```